# PHP Form Does Not Inject Message into Div in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This is my first question here on Stack Overflow. I have all my code below and am hoping someone can help me with this. My PHP form sends fine and is working, however my goal is to have the message after sending being placed into a Div on the HTML page. I can't figure out why this isn't working on my staging site.

Here is my JS/HTML

```js
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "connect.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {

                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div style="border: 1px solid #c8c8c8; background-color: #282828; color: #c8c8c8; font-weight: 400" class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button style="color: #c8c8c8; top: -5px; right: 5px" type="button" class="message close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
   <div class="container">
                      <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="connect.php" role="form">
              
                        <div class="messages"></div>
                    
                        <div class="controls">
              
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
                                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required"
                                  data-error="Please Include Your Name">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_lastname">Company *</label>
                                <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="company" class="form-control" required="required"
                                  data-error="Please Include Your Company">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required"
                                  data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="4" required="required"
                                  data-error="Please Include A Message"></textarea>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2 sm-2 md-2 lg-2 mx-auto">
                              <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

I hope this is enough for someone to help me on this one. My apoligies for any issues with how it was presented, as I mentioned, first time poster. The good news is the PHP sending is fine. It's a matter of why it's not being injected into the Messages Div.

Comment: Look at the network request in the browser dev tools. Does the response contain the expected data? If so, how does it look?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked there and it shows the POST function in the PHP file is occurring fine, and the Form Data shows up fine as well once I click the button and the request is sent. My issue is that instead of injecting the confirmation into the Messages Div, it just loads the .php page.

Comment: Try tracing it - in the browser dev tools add a breakpoint to see if it gets into "success" function... If it does, go step by step to see if all likes are executed...  It may give some clues

Comment: You need to call `e.preventDefault()` or else the form will make you navigate there.

Comment: another tip: add a handler for error in .ajax call, 

error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
      console.log('Error!', xhr.responseText, textStatus);  },

Comment: I figured it out!! Thanks so much for your help everyone!! Basically, using the dev tools allowed me to find an error which oddly, was in my HTML file. Basically, I messed up and installed the slim version of jQuery for some reason. The PHP/JS code itself wasn't even the issue.